# Переход в активити в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android

Помимо фрагментов, хочу добавить переход и в активити в своём navigation drawer

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragment = new MainFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragment = new SecondFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Если при переходе по фрагментам проблем не возникает, то при переходе в MainActivity выбивает ошибку

> ```
>               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что код в вашем методе продолжает выполняться и после вызова `startActivity()`. В методе вы присваиваете экземпляру fragment значение null, затем не инициализируете его (соответствующие ветки условий пропускаются) и далее (после вызова второй активити) пытаетесь вызвать фрагмент, который равен null, о чем и получаете ошибку.

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_camera :
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery :
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SecondFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow :
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.
"Поизящней", в двух словах наводку можно получить? Возможно получится применить. Плюс интересно узнать, почему это решение не совсем удачное.

Comment: @VadimMorozov Первое что пришло в голову из "поизящней"  :)